# How can I adjust the NavigationBar height to show an inserted SubView

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am trying to insert a sub view in the NavigationBar that needs to appear on all screens across the app. The code used to insert is below

```
          ConnectionBarController statusBar = (ConnectionBarController)UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null).InstantiateViewController("ConnectionBarController");
        if (NavigationController != null)
        {
            this.NavigationController.View.Add(statusBar.View);
            // var frame = this.NavigationController.View.Frame;
            // frame.Height += ConnectionBarController.FrameHeight;
            //  this.NavigationController.View.Frame = frame;
       }
```

It seems to appear, but the NavBar is cut off. Any suggestions on how to get this working?

I cant post a screen shot, as I am short of 2 reputations. Let me know if anyone needs to see the screenshot

Comment: Try posting a screenshot now.